# How can I repeat an animation (CSS and Javascript onclick)

Tags: javascript, css, animation

How can I repeat an animation which is set with CSS and Javascript by `onclick`?
I am a very beginner code writer and know HTML, CSS and Javascript. I do not know why the following online click and function just work once. I will appreciate if you help me.

## Code

```js
function discharge() {
    document.getElementById("electron").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("electron").style.WebkitAnimation = "mymove 5s 1   backwards"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
    document.getElementById("submit").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    document.getElementById("submit").style.boxShadow = "0px 3px 3px red";
    document.getElementById("submit1").style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
    document.getElementById("submit1").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px red";
}
```

```css
#electron {
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0% {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    25% {
        left: -32px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    50% {
        left: -32px;
        top: -20px;
    }
    75% {
        left: 158px;
        top: -20px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 158px;
        top: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button id="submit" onclick="discharge()">Discharge</button>
    <button id="submit1">charge</button>
</div>

<div id="electron">
    <br /><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
    <br /><i class="fa fa-minus-   circle"></i>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Where's `charge()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this answer to solve your issues

html

```
    <div>
  <button id="submit" onclick="discharge()">Discharge</button>
  <button id="submit1" onclick="charge()">charge</button>
</div>

<div id="electron">
  <br/><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
  <br/><i class="fa fa-minus-   circle"></i>
  <br/>
</div>
```

javascript

```
discharge = function() {
  document.getElementById("electron").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("electron").style.WebkitAnimation = "mymove 5s 1   backwards"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
  document.getElementById("submit").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  document.getElementById("submit").style.boxShadow = "0px 3px 3px red";
  document.getElementById("submit1").style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
  document.getElementById("submit1").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px red";
}

charge = function(){
document.getElementById("electron").removeAttribute('style');
document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute('style');
document.getElementById("submit1").removeAttribute('style');
}
```

No change in css.

Answer (score 1):

the given javascript code having an issue with defining function.
Please use `discharge = function (){` 
There are some missing elements like `electron` and `li`
Also i cannot find any function called `charge()`

So i have commented missing elements and provided below.

```
discharge = function () {
// document.getElementById("electron").style.visibility = "visible";
// document.getElementById("li").style.visibility = "visible";
// document.getElementById("electron").style.WebkitAnimation = "mymove 5s 1   backwards"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
document.getElementById("submit").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
document.getElementById("submit").style.boxShadow = "0px 3px 3px red";
document.getElementById("submit1").style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
document.getElementById("submit1").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px red";}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. This is the correct version:

Comment: I fixed in the question section. Thanks for your help. I look forward  to hearing from you.

Comment: Yes, that also fine.

Comment: Would you please help how I can fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You have changed the function and it is working. what else is the issue?

Comment: The problem is the onclick is just working once and after that when I click it does not work.

Comment: I have added another answer with all changes. I hope that will fixed your issue. I have used `removeAttribute('style')` to reset the styles. Please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

How I managed it was with a timeout and an extra class:

```js
function doFadeOut()
{
  let f = document.getElementById('f');
  f.classList.remove('unseen');
  setTimeout(() =>
  {
    f.classList.add('unseen');
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#f
{
    opacity:0%;
    animation: fadeout 2s linear 1;
}

    #f.unseen
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity:100%;
        animation:inherit;
    }

@keyframes fadeout
{
    from
    {
        opacity: 100%;
    }

    to
    {
        opacity: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="f" class="unseen">
this will appear then fade out with every click of the button below
</div>
<button onclick="doFadeOut()">show the message</button>
```

The main trick seems to be switching the CSS animation property at the end of the animation.

The way I have done it couples the time in the CSS with the time in the JS, making it a little brittle, so if there is an easy way to only set the time once, that would be great.